# If statement to look into files

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# This would match files that begin with YYYYMMDD format.
files=(*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].wav)

# If you want to match those in the current year, start it with that year instead.
# current_year=$(date +%Y)
# files=("$current_year"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)

#expands its values to multiple arguments '${files[@]}'
for file in ${files[@]}; do
file_date=${file:(-12):8}
file_year=${file_date:0:4}  
file_month=${file_date:4:2}

#  Adding -p option to mkdir would create the directory only if it doesn't exist.
  mkdir -p "$file_year"

  file_month=${file:4:2}
  cd  $file_year
  mkdir -p "$file_month"
  cd ..
  mv $files "$file_year"/"$file_month"

done
```

Getting errors line 20: cd: -9: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]
mv: invalid option -- '9'
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Comment: Quote ``for file in "${files[@]}"; do`` and ``cd "$file_year"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# When a match is not found, just present nothing.
shopt -s nullglob

# Match all .wav files containing the date format.
files=(*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.wav)

if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No match found."
fi

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    # We get the date part by part
    file_date=''
    # Split it into parts.
    IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
    for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
            # Break from the loop if a match is found
        if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
            file_date=$t
            break
        fi
    done
    # If a value was not assigned, then show an error message and continue to the next file.
    if [[ -z $file_date ]]; then
        echo "Unable to find date string in $file."
        continue
    fi

    file_year=${file_date:0:4}
    file_month=${file_date:4:2}

    mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

    # -- is just there to not interpret filenames starting with - as options.
    echo mv -- "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"
done
```

Comment: if I use yours it these errors mkdir: invalid option -- '9'
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
./years.sh: line 20: cd: -9: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]
mv: invalid option -- '9'
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Comment: @Ryan You should quote your variables properly around double quotes to prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html). Also on your mv command I noticed that you're still using the variable `"$files"` instead of just `"$file"`.

Comment: I am using the code you just wrote by copy and paste and got this....mkdir --help' for more information. ./years.sh: line 20: cd: -9: invalid option cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir] mv: invalid option -- '9' Try mv --help' for more information  .... if i do the " how am i getting the qrong ones

Comment: @Ryan I made an update. Can you run it again and show the output here in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)? I want to see how the expansions are not working as expected.

Comment: @Ryan Where's the link?

Comment: @Ryan The pattern actually didn't match anything. Were those files really in those format? i.e. (*YYYYMMDD.wav). Or perhaps it's in uppercase?

Comment: let me copy the excat files give me a min

Comment: q1024-20130912-042917-1378974556.3431212.wav and wanna di it by yr and month with is q1024-(20130912)-042917-1378974556.3431212.wav

Comment: Sorry for that I gave wrong file names sorry for the Hassle but your good at what you do!!!!! and dang your quick

Comment: @Ryan Are there files that are exactly `OUT117-(20130908)-223406-1378694046.3384377.wav`?

Comment: Damn man your good any good basic books you want to get? Plus it worked like charm! If you were here I would buy you dinner lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a bash expert but there are a couple of ways to do it.

- You can incorporate the other cases into your `files` matcher.
- You can develop other matchers that cover the cases you want, and check each in turn

Pseudocode for the second:

```
# This would match files that begin with YYYYMMDD format.
files=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)

# This would match the "OUTXXX-" files (just conceptually, but you get the idea).
files_out=(OUT[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)

# etc.

# Now process each matched list in turn
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you edited your original question, you had some filenames like this: `OUTxxx - 20130913.wav`. Based on this file name you can do the following. It also works for filename `qxxxx - 20130913.wav` or `xxxx- 20130913.wav`.

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.wav"); 
do 
  fn=$(echo $file | sed -e 's/.*- //g' -e 's/\.wav//g');
  fyear=${fn:0:4};
  fmonth=${fn:4:2};
  fdate=${fn:6:2};
  echo $fyear; echo $fmonth;echo $fdate;
  mkdir -p "$fyear"/"$fmonth";
  mv $fn "$fyear"/"$fmonth";
done
```

Comment: I wouldnt want to do an ls ststaement because i have way to many files for that trust me

Comment: You can replace `\ls -1` with `find`. Edited my answer.